# реализовать что-то типа ленивой загрузки

Tags: java, proxy, lazyloading

Есть `HashMap<PageType, Page>`
 - изначально заполненная всеми возможными значениями (значения мапы равны null).
Во время выполнения значения могут изменяться!

Есть класс, который должен хранить АКТУАЛЬНОЕ значение по конкретному ключу, типа такого:

```
public class ConfitmS{
    private Page confirmationPage;
    ...
}
```

Предполагаю что это следует реализовать через прокси, но как не знаю
а может и не через прокси можно.
Подскажите как это сделать, либо в какую сторону копать, наверняка должно быть простое решение. (Ещё в башке летают мысли создать аспект, который перед каждым методом тупо пересетает confirmationPage, но это полная дичь).

Answer (score 2):

Не нужен тут прокси, достаточно использовать [соответствующий метод интерфейса Map](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#computeIfAbsent-K-java.util.function.Function-)

```
Page page = someMap.computeIfAbsent(somePageType, ConfitmS::getActualValue);
```

*Или что-то типа этого.*

Comment: этот метод не предоставляет ленивой загрузки, он просто инициализирует объект page один раз - никакого связывания с мапой не будет. То есть после изменения значения в мапе объект page будет не актуальным.